# Pegar os dados selecionados em um v-select multiple

Tags: vue.js

Pessoal estou precisando retornar em um v-select multiple apenas os valores selecionados em um array, estou tentando há algum tempo sem sucesso, ele retorna o objeto completo e como estou usando em um form venho tendo problemas.

```
    new Vue({
              el:"#app",
data : {
                criterios : '',
                criterios_list: [
                {'value' : 'S_cheque', 'label' : 'S/cheque'},
                {'value' : 'S_cartao', 'label' : 'S/cartão Faturado'},
                {'value' : 'Somente_cartao', 'label' : 'Somente cartão Faturado'}]
}
});

<v-select multiple v-model="criterios" :options="criterios_list"></v-select>
{{criterios}}
```

Comment: Esse componente `v-select` é de que biblioteca?

Comment: @Sergio Pela sintaxe é do [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/vuetify/quick-start).

Comment: @guastallaigor pois também achei mas queria ter a certeza antes de responder :)

Answer (score -1):

Não sei se é a melhor forma, mas consegui resolver esse problema transformando o elemento em um array simples:

```
    new Vue({
              el:"#app",
data : {
                criterios : '',
                criterios_list: ['S/cheque','S/cartão Faturado']
}
});

<v-select multiple v-model="criterios" :options="criterios_list"></v-select>
{{criterios}}
```

Comment: Oi Victor, viste a minha pergunta nos comentários?

Answer (score -1):

Segundo a [documentação do Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects#example-custom-text-and-value), você pode usar as propriedades `item-text` e `item-value` com as chaves do objeto para personalizar isso.

Segue seu exemplo modificado.

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data: {
    criterios : '',
    criterios_list: [
      {'value' : 'S_cheque', 'label' : 'S/cheque'},
      {'value' : 'S_cartao', 'label' : 'S/cartão Faturado'},
      {'value' : 'Somente_cartao', 'label' : 'Somente cartão Faturado'}]
  }
});
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-select multiple v-model="criterios"
              :items="criterios_list" 
              item-text="label"
              item-value="value"></v-select>
    {{criterios}}
  </v-app>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<v-select multiple 
    v-model="criterios" 
    :options="criterios_list"
    label="label"
    value="value">
</v-select>
```

Comment: Por mais que a resposta venha a ser útil, seria interessante explicar o que estás a fazer, assim, facilita o entendimento do autor da pergunta e de futuras consultas.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar o reduce

```
<v-select multiple v-model="criterios" :reduce="(x) => x.value" :options="criterios_list"/>
```